# How can I show that these two sets in the complex plane are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $c > 0$ and $I$ be the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Let the set $A$ be defined as
$$
A = \left\{cI + \frac{2c}{z} \left(I - \frac{1}{z}I\right)^{-1} : z \in \mathbb C, |z| > 1\right\}
$$
and let the set $B$ be defined as
$$
B = \left\{\frac{1}{s}I : s \in \mathbb C, \text{Re}\{s\} > 0\right\}
$$
How can I show that $A = B$?

Here is what I've tried so far: let $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ such that $|z_0| > 1$. I want to show that the expression
$$
cI + \frac{2c}{z_0} \left(I - \frac{1}{z_0}I\right)^{-1}
$$
can be expressed as $\frac{1}{s_0}I$ for some $s_0 \in \mathbb C$ such that $\text{Re}\{s_0\} > 0$. This expression can be simplified to
$$
\begin{align}
cI + \frac{2c}{z_0} \left(I - \frac{1}{z_0}I\right)^{-1} &= cI + \frac{2c}{z_0} \left(I - z_0I\right) \\
&= cI + \frac{2c}{z_0} \left(I - z_0I\right) \\
&= \frac{cz_0}{z_0}I + \frac{2c(1-z_0)}{z_0}I \\
&= \frac{cz_0I + 2c(1-z_0)I}{z_0} \\
&= \frac{2cI - cz_0I}{z_0} \\
\end{align}
$$
However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Assume and element is in A, then prove it must be in B. Then, assume and element is in B, and prove it is also in A.

Comment: Your computations seem to suggest that $\left(I - \frac{1}{z_0}I\right)^{-1} = I - z_0 I$, but this is wrong. Instead, write $I - \frac{1}{z_0}I = \left(1 - \frac{1}{z_0}\right) I = \frac{z_0 - 1}{z_0}I$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. First note that
$$
cI + \frac{2c}{z} \left(I - \frac{1}{z}I\right)^{-1}=cI+\frac{2c}{z}\left(1-\frac1{z}\right)^{-1}I=\left(1+\frac{2}{z-1}\right)cI=\frac{z+1}{z-1}cI
$$
Also note that $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ if and only if $\operatorname{Re}(z^{-1})=\operatorname{Re}(\frac{\bar z}{|z|^2})=\operatorname{Re}(z)/|z|^2>0$, therefore $B=\{zI: \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$.

However is clear that $cI\in B$ but there is no $|z|>1$ such that $\frac{z+1}{z-1}=1$, therefore $cI\notin A$.∎

Comment: I'm not sure how your conclusions are relevant here. Please see my answer.

Comment: Hi Masacroso, just following up after a while. Based on my understanding of this answer, it is true that $A \subseteq B$, but you showed with your last sentence that $A \nsupseteq B$. Is this correct? If so, then this would make sense of why my answer below is wrong, because I assumed that the proof for $A \supseteq B$ would be the proof of $A \subseteq B$ but in reverse order.